# Como fazer as primeiras letras que o usuário digitar serem maiúsculas?

Tags: c++

Um exemplo,

> joão augusto

Como fazer a primeira letra do nome e sobrenome seja maiúscula ficando:

> João Augusto

Comment: Supondo que não existam espaços desnecessários em sua string (no início, no fim ou duplicados) modifique para maiúscula o primeiro caractere e todos os demais que sejam precedidos de espaço.

Answer (score 1):

Assim, estás a obrigar o utilizador a colocar a primeira letra maiuscula

```
char nome[50];

do{
printf("Qual o nome?\n");
scanf("%c", nome);
}while (nome[0]>='a' && nome[0]<='z');
```

Comment: Quero em C++, querido.

Answer (score 0):

Algo disto

```
string name;
do{
cout << "Qual o nome?";
getline (cin,name);
}while (nome[0]>='A' && nome[0]<='Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar a função `toupper()` que recebe um valor inteiro correspondente ao valor ASCII de um caractere e retorna o valor inteiro ASCII da versão maiúscula desse caractere, se existir. Essa função está definida no header `<cctype>`.

```
int toupper (int ch);
```

Como a função trabalha com os valores inteiros, você pode usar casting de tipos para usar os valores em caracteres. Você pode passar um caractere como parâmetro com o casting `(int)` e retornar o valor para o mesmo caractere usando o casting `(char)`.

Por exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nome;

    cout << "Digite seu nome: ";
    cin >> nome;

    // o primeiro char do nome recebe a versão maiúscula dele mesmo
    nome[0] = (char) toupper( (int) nome[0] );

    cout << nome << endl;
}
```

Recomendo que priorize armazenar os nomes em `strings` ao invés de vetores de `char`.

Para aplicar a vários nomes, podes ler usando o comando `getline(cin, nome)` e usar em qualquer estrutura de repetição, recomendo fortemente o `for`.

Espero ter ajudado.